# Remove solution/folder name from url in sitefinity project while running on localhost

Tags: asp.net, telerik, sitefinity

I have one Telerik sitefinity project developed  on other machine. When I configure the project on my system and run on localhost it takes folder/solution name in url. Therefore while clicking on links it give 404 not found error.

Url created now is:-
http://localhost:xxxx/ProjectName/home

What I want is:-
http://localhost:xxxx/home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new website in IIS and point it to the project folder. 
Then browse it using the host header of the site, e.g. localhost or even something like mysite.localtest.me (*.localtest.me will point to 127.0.0.1)